# Animation bag with some ImageViews

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have problem with my android animation. When I click the first time on my ImageView, my image have a rotation but when click the second time on my ImageView, rotation don't work. Why is it happened?

My rotation method in Java code:

```
private boolean tomIsInvisible = false;



public void eraseTom(View view) {
    ImageView tom = findViewById(R.id.tom);
    ImageView jerry = findViewById(R.id.jerry);

    if (tomIsInvisible) {

        tom.animate()
                .rotation(3600)
                .scaleX(1)
                .scaleY(1)
                .alpha(1)
                .setDuration(3000);

        jerry.animate()
                .rotation(3600)
                .scaleX(0)
                .scaleY(0)
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(3000);

        tomIsInvisible = false;

    } else if(!tomIsInvisible) {

        tom.animate()
                .rotation(3600)
                .scaleX(0)
                .scaleY(0)
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(3000);

        jerry.animate()
                .rotation(3600)
                .alpha(1)
                .scaleX(1)
                .scaleY(1)
                .setDuration(3000);

        tomIsInvisible = true;
    }
}
```

Others methods on my ImageView work correctly.

Comment: Please, share your onClick code where you are calling `eraseTom()`. Are Tom and Jerry one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `rotation(3600)` first time it animates `rotation` from `0` to `3600`. (default view rotation is `0`). After first animation `rotation` is `3600` (`ViewPropertyAnimator` changes actual value of property while it animate things). So when you call `rotation(3600)` second time `rotation` of your view is already `3600` and you try to animate it to `3600`. Thats why there is no visual changes. There is [rotationBy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#rotationBy(float)) method which apply specified value to view rotation, try to use it.

```
view.animate().rotationBy(3600)
```

Another solution is to animate from 0 to 360 and in the animation end reset view rotation to 0.